# How can I run two files in javascript with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I am new to javascript and Node.js and having problems testing some code I wrote recently. I am trying to test code written in a file called "compareCrowe.js" with "testCrowe.js" using Node.js.

Here are the contents of testCrowe.js:

```
var compareCrowe = required['./compareCrowe'];
    console.log('begin test');
    var connection = {Type:1, Label:"label", linkTo:null};
    var table1 = {name:"table1", body:"description1", out:[connection]};
    var table2 = {name:"table2", body:"description2", out:null};
    connection.linkTo = table2;
    var crowe = [table1, table2];
    var result = compareCrowe.compareCrowesFoot(crowe, crowe);
    console.log(result.feedback);
```

where the function "compareCrowesFoot" is defined in compareCrowe.js. From the console on an Ubuntu virtual machine I ran:

```
node compareCrowe.js testCrowe.js
```

however, nothing was printed. There were no errors or warnings or explanation of any kind. It didn't even print the "begin test" line I placed at the top of testCrowe.js. If I run the command:

```
node testCrowe.js
```

it complains that compareCrowesFoot is undefined. How can I test the contents of compareCrowe.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it seems like you've got your syntax a little messed up. It should be more like:

```
var compareCrowe = require('./compareCrowe.js');
```

That would make any methods you've exported in `compareCrowe.js`, such as your `compareCrowe.compareCrowesFoot` function, available to `testCrowe.js`.

Then, in your terminal, you would run the following:

```
node testCrowe.js
```

And that should do the trick provided you don't have any further errors in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the party of JS.

I'm not sure where you're learning from, but a few of the resources that have helped me and many others are [superherojs.com](http://superherojs.com), [nodeschool.io](http://nodeschool.io), the [MDN developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), [Node.js API docs](http://nodejs.org/api), and Youtube (seriously).

The basic idea of Node.js is that it operates with [modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (chunks of reusable code), which is what [NPM](http://npmjs.org) is made up of. These can then be included in other modules and used anywhere else in your application.

So for a basic example, say you had **compareCrowe.js**, to make it includable/reusable in another file, you could write something like:

```
module.exports = function() { 
    var compareCrowesFoot = function(crowe1, crowe2) { /* compare crows feet and return something here */ }

    return { compareCrowesFoot: compareCrowesFoot }; 
    // return an object with a property of whatever you want to access it as , and the value as your function name
    // e.g. - you could return { compare: compareCrowesFoot };
}
```

Then in **testCrowe.js** you could require compareCrowe like this:

```
var compareCrowe = require("./compareCrowe");

/* your code here... */
var result = compareCrowe.compareCrowesFoot(crowe1, crowe2);
// if your returned object was { compare: compareCrowesFoot };
// this would be compareCrowe.compare(crowe1, crowe1);
```

And to run your tests, you could then run `node testCrowe.js` from the command line.